# Check if a record exists based on date and user id, if not create it, if so update it -while adding values instead of replacing them

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a php page with a sql script (MySql) that will check if a user has already added a record for that day.  If they have not, I want to create the record.  If they have I want to update the record with new information.

For example:

```
1) no record found... add the following info
    user_id     number
    --------    ------
    00001       1

2) database now looks like this
index       date                user_id     number
-----       -----               --------    -------
1       2015-03-23 11:41:51     00001       1


3. php page is called again by the same user the same day month and year just a few minutes later with the following data:
    user_id     number
    --------    ------
    00001       5

4) database should now looks like this
index       date                user_id     number
-----       -----               --------    -------
1       2015-03-23 11:41:51     00001       6 <---notice the numbers are added


5) if the user calls the php page the following day I want it to create a new record.
```

I'm not sure if this can be done with only sql or if there is php code that needs to be added as well, any help would be appreciated thanks.

------------------edit----------------------------

code I use to add a new record.

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO myTable(user_id, number)  
VALUES(00001,1)");
```

I'm not sure how to check for a record with the day/time/year along with the user_id, or how to add the `numbers` as in the example above.

Comment: see the edit I made above.

Comment: That's just the code how you insert into the DB. Have you written any code (SELECT statement) how to find out whether the user has already a record for the day? BTW: of Course this is possible with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with those 3 steps :

1. Create a column named `day` in your table that contains just the day date (without time).
2. Create an index of type `unique` on the `day` and `user_id`.
3. Use the `on duplicate key` statement within your insert to trigger an update if the entry already exists for that user and for that day :

   `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;`

Taken from : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: This doesn't appear to make sure both the day AND user_id are unique. For example yesterday it updated and work just as it should, but today (different date) it continues to update yesterdays record instead of create a new one. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you create an index of type `unique` on both columns : `day` and `user_id` ? Also, if you want more help, you may want to provide the SQL of your table structure with the query you are executing to update.

Comment: I set both to unique when I created the table in phpmyadmin.  I ran `desc mytable` and it shows `user_id` and unique and `date` as primary instead of unique (does that make a difference) it wont let me change it to unique. I'm using the query you mentioned above `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;`

Comment: Drop your existing indexes for those columns and create ONE single index for those 2 columns. Again, it has to be 1 single index of type `unique`.